# Remove installation's base currency from order summary in admin

Tags: admin, multistore, currency

Does anyone know a quick way to remove the base currency from the order summary detail from within Magento's admin panel?

For example at the moment on our multi store setup we have order summary displaying like so:

```
Grand Total £447.60
           [€523.43]
```

We want to display the totals in just the store currency that the order was placed in (in this case €'s)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit hackish, but it works just fine.
Add an event observer for the `controller_action_layout_render_before_adminhtml_sales_order_view` event to your modules config.xml

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <controller_action_layout_render_before_adminhtml_sales_order_view>
            <observers>
                <your_module>
                    <class>your_module/observer</class>
                    <method>controllerActionLayoutRenderBeforeAdminhtmlSalesOrderView</method>
                </your_module>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_render_before_adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Then, in the observer class, add the following method:

```
public function controllerActionLayoutRenderBeforeAdminhtmlSalesOrderView()
{
    /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order */
    if ($order = Mage::registry('current_order')) {
        if ($order->isCurrencyDifferent()) {
            // Update order on the fly to only display the store currency and hide the base currency
            $order->setBaseCurrencyCode($order->getOrderCurrencyCode());
        }
    }
}
```

Because the order base currency is only overridden during that request, and the order isn't saved, it in effect only changes the order info display.